# “Configchanges.Locale” not working to reflect the change in language selected from device settings

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, locale, android-configchanges

I have added "ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.Locale" in MainActivity. Upon changing language from settings, the app restarts when selected from background but language change is not reflected. It changes only when brought back from killed state. Am I missing something? Please enlighten me.

```
[Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Icon = "@drawable/appicon", ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait, MainLauncher = true, LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleInstance, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.Locale )]
```

Comment: After referring to the link by @Sushi, have you solved your problem? Or are there any error?

Comment: I tried the solution provided in the suggested link, but the method is not being called. I am getting the splashscreen of my app when launching app from background meaning a restart and in SetLocale() I am able to see the language has changed. But still old language is shown for strings.